# Right place for user specific enviroment variables if you don't use a display manager

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, environment-variables, pam

I recently purged my display manager in favor of starting xsessions with startx. I did this after setting up a new installation of ubuntu 18.04.

Up to now I was used to use `~/.pam_environment` to set up environment variables for a user. For example I add my `~/bin` path to `PATH` like this:

```
PATH    DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin
```

In the new system this doesn't seem to be recognized anymore. So what would the best place to define user specific environment variables?

My `startx` setup works like this:

Using `zsh` as login-shell, my `~/.zlogin` file contains something like:

```
if [ $(tty) = "/dev/tty3" ]; then
    exec startx -- :3 vt3 &>/dev/null
    logout
fi
```

And `~/.xinitrc` something like:

```
xsetroot -cursor_name arrow
exec xmonad
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `zsh` on ubuntu the `~/.zshenv` is the correct place for exported variables like `$PATH`, `$EDITOR`, ... (This doesn't work on [Arch linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Startup.2FShutdown_files))